# Flow Template: This flow’s Source Template is not a template or doesn’t exist

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package

I've packaged a flow template with my managed package. In the subscriber org, when I create a new flow using this template, flow loads fine in flow builder, but gives this error on save -

`This flow’s Source Template CloudFiles_Set_Connected_Folder is not a template or doesn’t exist.`

The error code from network call is this `FLOW_SOURCE_TEMPLATE_INVALID_REFERENCE`

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior in my org too. While I have inputs from the concerned Salesforce team, I observed that when you add this template flow from the managed package as a "Sub Flow" element, this error does not occur. Let me know if it works in your scenario. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Using it as a subflow won't address my use case

Comment: Can you share more details on your usecase?

Comment: As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) , isTemplate : `Indicates whether the process or flow is a template. When installed from managed packages, processes and flows can’t be viewed or cloned by subscribers because of intellectual property (IP) protection. But when those processes and flows are templates, subscribers can open them in a builder, clone them, and customize the clones. Available in API version 45.0 and later.` I was able to clone the packaged template and use it.

Comment: By clone, do you mean, creating a new flow using a template?

Comment: Open the flow of managed package> Save As>This saved one can be modified and saved as copy

Comment: Does the provided information help or do you have any follow up queries? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) ,

> isTemplate : Indicates whether the process or flow is a template. When installed from managed packages, processes and flows can’t be viewed or cloned by subscribers because of intellectual property (IP) protection. But when those processes and flows are templates, subscribers can open them in a builder, clone them, and customize the clones. Available in API version 45.0 and later.

You need to clone the packaged template(Open the flow of managed package> Save As>This saved one can be modified and saved as new copy) to be able to use it.

Incase, the flow's isTemplate field is not checked and packaged, the flow's components will not be visible in subscriber org.